# How to get questions length while it has filtered with some value in angular js?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

How to get `question length` while it has been filtered with other value using angular js?

- [My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1IPNkuZz8KmfL4WZtvqO?p=preview)
- Actually I am trying to get the filtered question length so we have used this `Total no of questions:{{question.length}}` to get the answer but it's showing overall questions length like:- `4`.
- If we used a filter like: `| filter:{status: 'pending'}` there are 2 data's only showing on the table, so I want to show this filtered questions length only and expecting an answer like: `2`
- Please look at my plunker for reference [My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/B5HuFad9PUOSrJ5yVDTz?p=preview).

**My Html:-**

```
<tr ng-repeat="mani in  resultValue=((question) | filter:{status: 'pending'})  ">
    <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
    <td>{{mani.title}}</td>
    <td>{{mani.upvotes }}</td>
    <td>{{question.length}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>sum</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>{{resultValue | sumOfValue:'upvotes'}}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
<p class="color">Total no of questions :{{question.length}} </p>
<p>Total no of upvotes : {{resultValue | sumOfValue:'upvotes'}}</p>
<p>Total no of Open Eyes of [1 values] : {{resultValue | sumOfValue:'openeyes'}}</p>
<p>Total no of Open Eyes of [0 value] : {{resultValue | sumOfZeros:'openeyes'}}</p>
```

**Filter i have used :-**

```
filter:{status: 'pending'})
```

**My data:-**

```
     $scope.question = [
{
"_id": "5936a70095e3a85804aae050",
"user": {
"_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
"displayName": "Table 1",
"roles": [
"admin"
],
"profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/ownprofile/uploads/1f08308f43b0674d61a2cc5d95deb5ef",
"email": "ms@e21designs.com",
"categories": []
},
"__v": 1,
"status": "pending",
"openeyers": ["sarawana@gmail.com"],
"openeyes": 1,
"upvoters": [
"sarawana@gmail.com"
],
"upvotes": 1,
"title": "what is cricket",
"created": "2017-06-06T12:58:40.204Z"
},

{
"_id": "5979a913c999e9302caece15",
"user": {
"_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
"displayName": "karthi",
"roles": [
"admin"
],
"profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/ownprofile/uploads/1f08308f43b0674d61a2cc5d95deb5ef",
"email": "karthi@e21designs.com",
"categories": []
},
"__v": 1,
"status": "approved",
"openeyers": [],
"openeyes": 0,
"upvoters": [
"sarawana@gmail.com"
],
"upvotes": 1,
"title": "who fan you are",
"created": "2017-06-06T12:58:40.204Z"
},

{
"_id": "5936a70095e3a85804aae050",
"user": {
"_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
"displayName": "Table 1",
"roles": [
"admin"
],
"profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/ownprofile/uploads/1f08308f43b0674d61a2cc5d95deb5ef",
"email": "karthi@e21designs.com",
"categories": []
},
"__v": 1,
"status": "pending",
"openeyers": [],
"openeyes": 0,
"upvoters": [
"ms@e21designs.com",
"vp@gmail.com"
],
"upvotes": 2,
"title": "best of the day",
"created": "2017-06-06T12:58:40.204Z"
},

{
"_id": "5979a913c999e9302caece15",
"user": {
"_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
"displayName": "karthi",
"roles": [
"admin"
],
"profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/ownprofile/uploads/1f08308f43b0674d61a2cc5d95deb5ef",
"email": "ms@e21designs.com",
"categories": []
},
"__v": 1,
"status": "approved",
"openeyers": ["ms@e21designs.com"],
"openeyes": 1,
"upvoters": [
"ms@e21designs.com",
"vp@gmail.com","ms@gmail.com"
],
"upvotes": 0,
"title": "he is best",
"created": "2017-06-06T12:58:40.204Z"
},

]
```

- Expecting total no of question is like:- `2`, so please check my plunker and update the solution as well, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the question length code like this:

```
 <p class="color">Total no of questions :{{((question) | filter:{status: 'pending'}).length}} </p>
```

[Working plunkar link](http://plnkr.co/edit/glQZMdFjqo9yrB91lsXQ?p=preview)

Comment: :-) glad to help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{{resultValue.length}}` where resultValue is the filtered data

```
<p class="color">Total no of questions :{{resultValue.length}} </p>
```

**Working Plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/IiI1L6JjnWorIQCaWWIU?p=preview